# Expressjs not sure how to handle multiple users

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

This is more of a conceptual question. I am trying to build an expressjs app in which when a user starts I would need to make a temp folder for each user to store some files. I am not sure how to handle this scenario.

I am not much experienced on server side development and this would be my first node/expressjs project.

I am sorry no code yet as I am still clueless how to approach the above problem. I looked into express-session and my current approach would be to create a session and use session id a the folder name.

can anybody guide me towards a more robust approach.

Comment: if user is temporary then session_id may work but you need to ensure what is uploaded is not infected.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to use Node file system:

https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_mkdtemp_prefix_callback

There are also lots of npm packages for this you could use which might make it even simpler.

something like this: https://www.npmjs.com/package/tmp

Since you are using sessions, get the username out of the session and then use that to along with a timestamp to create a folder name that wouldn't run into any duplicate names.